# access Freeform mp_data of upload field with multiple files

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, file-uploads

as far as said situation is concerned, i only get one string of all the file names joined. Is it possible to loop through them or even get the files full paths?

```
{freeform:mp_data:my_multiple_upload_field}
```

I want to use this for a summary of all submitted content and the end of the form.

Comment: Turns out the p wrapped ul generated with the input tag that i hid because of the empty space it generates does contain the uploaded files when repeated on the following page. Unfortunately for some reason this only worked for the field with binary uploads. Had to split the images string the posted code generates by extention. What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I would guess that the File Upload field tag pair can be used the same way within a multi-page form as it can be used within a Freeform Entries loop.

```
{freeform:mp_data:my_multiple_upload_field}
    {freeform:fileurl}
    {freeform:server_path}
    {freeform:filename}
    {freeform:extension}
    {freeform:filesize}
{/freeform:mp_data:my_multiple_upload_field}}
```

([Docs.](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#file_upload))